# BeginForm html helper doesn't work with file upload

Tags: asp.net-mvc, file-upload

I have a strongly typed view, a model and a simple post method.

Model has one property:

```
public HttpPostedFileBase File { get; set; }
```

View looks as follows:

```
<form method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">
        <input type="submit" name="Put" value="Excel" />
</form>
```

And an action is

```
[HttpPost]
public virtual ActionResult Method(ModelVM model)
{
   ...
}
```

What I've just shown works. But when I change explicit form declaration to the following code:

```
@using (Html.BeginForm(MVC.SomeController.Actions.ActionNames.Method, MVC.SomeController.Name))
```

Then the action method don't bind the file to the model.

Does anybody know why?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Because you haven't added `enctype` attribute to the form:

```
@using (Html.BeginForm(MVC.SomeController.Actions.ActionNames.Method,
        MVC.SomeController.Name,
        FormMethod.Post,
        new { enctype = "multipart/form-data" }))
{
    ...
}
```

Answer (score 1):

When you use `Html.BeginForm`, it omits the `enctype` attribute which must be `multipart/form-data` for file attachments.

Use the overload of `BeginForm` that allows setting attributes like this:

```
@using (Html.BeginForm(MVC.SomeController.Actions.ActionNames.Method, MVC.SomeController.Name, FormMethod.Post, new { enctype = "multipart/form-data" }))
```